# Get Specific Data from json file using vue

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I am trying to add a select option. In this option there should be the name of the employees. Once an employee is selected vue should render its profile information something like this:

- Name: Bob
- Title: Mr
- Gender: Male

All information is stored in a json file.

```
<div id="app">
<div class="field">
        <label class="label employee-name">Employee Name</label>
        <div class="control">
         <select v-model="employee" class="is-small">
            <option v-for="employees in employees">{{ employee.name }}</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <pre>{{ employee.name }}, {{ employee.gender }}, {{ employee.designation }}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/json" src="./json/employees.json"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        employee: null,
        employees: ''
    },
    created: function () {
      fetch("/json/employees.json")
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(employees => {
          this.employee=employees;
       });
    }
});
</script>
```

And the json file is something like this:

```
[{
  "name": "Bob",
  "gender": "male",
  "title": "Mr"
}, {
  "name": "Alice",
  "gender": "female",
  "title": "Mrs"
}]
```

I think there is something wrong with the function. Any help would be appreciated.

PS: The browser console do not show any error or warning.

Comment: You have a typo here: `<option v-for="employees in employees">{{ employee.name }}</option>` . It should be `v-for="employee in employees"`

Comment: And another typo in your fetch callback, should be `this.employees = employees` instead of `this.employee = employees`. You're saving the full list of employees to a single employee state variable.

Comment: Thanks @ISAE and Chase DeAnda for pointing out the typos. But How could I make the select button to shows the names. But after selecting it does not render other details.

Comment: I think somehow I have to bind the select option with {{ employee.name }}, {{ employee.gender }}, {{ employee.designation }}

Comment: OK. I figured it out. <option v-for="employees in employees">{{ employee.name }}</option> should be <option v-for="employee in employees" v-bind:value="employee">{{ employee.name }}</option>